# Curl error (56) while trying to install Zabbix packages on RHEL 8

Tags: redhat, curl, zabbix, rhel8

I followed the instructions here https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=5.4&os_distribution=red_hat_enterprise_linux&os_version=8&db=mysql&ws=apache to install Zabbix 5.4 Mysql/Apache on my RHEL 8 server.

When i tried to install the package with `sudo dnf install zabbix-server-mysql` (or with yum) , i got this error :

```
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'zabbix':
  - Curl error (56): Failure when receiving data from the peer for https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.4/rhel/8/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml [Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'zabbix': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
```

- The thing is, if i try
  `curl https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.4/rhel/8/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml`
  => i'm able to retrieve content.
- In the other hand, if i try `curl -x http://proxy_user:user_pw@my_proxy:8080 https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/5.4/rhel/8/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml`  => i'm able to retrieve content too.

Proxy is set system-wide to access internet in /etc/environment =>
`http_proxy="http://proxy_user:user_pw@my_proxy:8080/" https_proxy="http://proxy_user:user_pw@my_proxy:8080/"`

every other repo (rhel repo, ansible repo etc...) are currently working, except for ZABBIX.

Did i miss anything in my current configuration ?

Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some researches i found out that RHEL repos (within /etc/yum.repos.d/) have proxy configured in every repo files. (maybe due to proxy-wide configuration ? i don't know...)

In my case :

- **i have to disable http_proxy & https_proxy in /etc/environment**
- i let proxy configured into every repos configuration files.

Then run `sudo dnf update` and `sudo dnf install zabbix-server-mysql` and everything runs smoothly !
(#auto-handshakes#)